# Exit fdisk list known partition types

Tags: fdisk

when setting up my linux installation I used the following command to create new partitions:

```
fdisk /dev/sda
```

After creating my partitions I was curious about the other optionsthe command has:
[image]

From this i tried option l to list all known partition types. Unfortunatly I could not exit the presented list. Neither ESC, Enter, CTL+C or CTL+X worked.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out eventually. The solution is to press

```
:q
```

followed by ENTER.